# Why there is no database file created and no operation is being done in Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

i am new to ios. I am trying to learn ios but till now i am not successful to do a CRUD in ios.

i was following a tutorial and there is no issue in code as well you will see code below.

1. i take an empty application with core data and ARC.
2. the make a an entity named Person (popular tutorial Example : www.youtube.com/watch?v=bC3F8a4F_KE)
3. then added sub class of `NSObject` named IMSPerson .
4. then added sub class of `UIVIEWCONTROLLER`.
5. then make an insertion method on btnSavePerson.

**The main problem is that i have no CORE DATA db file which tell me the data is being inserted...**

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CrudWithInterface.sqlite"];
```

where to find this file **CrudWithInterface.sqlite**

**Event of Save Button**

```
- (IBAction)btnAddPerson:(id)sender {
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *newPerson = [[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entityDesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newPerson setValue:self.txtFirstName.text forKey:@"firstName"];
    [newPerson setValue:self.txtFirstName.text forKey:@"lastName"];
    [newPerson setValue:self.txtFirstName.text forKey:@"address"];

    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];

    self.fldDisplayData.text = @"person Added Successfully... :)";

}
```

I have searched the path as well which was ~/User/Library/SharedAllication.....

And there is not IOS Simulator Folder in that....

Comment: is insertion code is ok... it should be ok because i have followed each and every step but still there may be a chance of error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

Step 1 : I don't see all the code for persistent store coordinator. It necessary to read or create NSPersistentStoreCoordinator if you want run app more times.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CrudWithInterface.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:<your managed Obbject Model>] retain];

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Suppression du model de données !!");
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:NULL];

        [_persistentStoreCoordinator release];
        _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:<your managed Obbject Model>];
        if (![singleton addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
        {
            abort();
        }
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

}

Step 2 : Now the save button (I don't now how you have creates your managedObjectContext named context) 
and you can static method "NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName" it's more useful

```
    - (IBAction)btnAddPerson:(id)sender {

        //Normaly you subclass NSManagedObject. On your modele file Editor menu "Create NSManaged subclass" 

        NSManagedObject *newPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"                                                       
inManagedObjectContext: context];
        [newPerson setValue:self.txtFirstName.text forKey:@"firstName"];
        [newPerson setValue:self.txtFirstName.text forKey:@"lastName"];
        [newPerson setValue:self.txtFirstName.text forKey:@"address"];

        NSError *error;
        if(![context save:&error])
        {
            DLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
        }

        self.fldDisplayData.text = @"person Added Successfully... :)";


    }
```

Comment: your edit leads me to some other problem know... :P          now I am blessed with this Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model error :)

Comment: have you replaced <your managed Object Model> by an instance of your Object model or nil ?